# Popovers don't work with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Following the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) I copied:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="bs-docs-example" style="padding-bottom: 24px;">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-danger" rel="popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?"
            data-original-title="A Title">Click to toggle popover</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HjJW6/)**

However it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it to work by doing two things:

1. As Popover relies on Tooltip, make sure bootstrap-tooltip.js is included before bootstrap-popover.js.
2. Activate the plugins with a line like `$('.container a').popover();`

To have the popup at the top add `data-placement="top"` to the `a` tag.

Comment: another option could be to use $('a[rel=popover]').popover() to ensure all popovers get initialized.

Comment: Thanks Owlvark and Gary. The winning combination was Owlvark #1 and @Gary.S's code. (Owlvark #2 didn't work). Gary.S: Can you post yours as an answer so I can upvote both of yours and checkbox one?

Comment: Also just wondering if either of you could have a solution using `popover top`? - Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

Popovers are not initialized by default. If you included an all-inclusive bootstrap.js (v 2.2, 2.3), initialize it by:

```
$('a[data-toggle=popover]').popover();
```

Comment: why, do you suppose, does data-toggle work for Modals and dropdowns out of the box, but not popovers?

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="#" id="LinkId">Text</a>
```

In document ready,

```
$("#LinkId").popover({ title: '', content: "Popover Content", placement: 'left|top|etc', trigger: 'hover' });
```

All you need include is `bootstrap.js`.